# Get Row As a Node in UI-Grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

if i use `$scope.mygrid.data[index]`, i take the following object (pure my own object):

[image]

But if i use a button on the same row and take the **row** as following: `ng-click="grid.appScope.anOperationSelected(row, \'BUTTON\')"` my received object is then a node (which i can use to navigate sub-trees)

[image]

My question is: How can i take the row as a node, just by using the index? (or at least others than using build-in buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so good way but it is possible to return it using GridApi:

```
$scope.GridApi.grid.rows.map(function (row) {
        if (row.entity.Name == yourWantedRow.Name) {
            $scope.theRow = row;
        }
    });
```